# Cannot implicitly convert type'bool?' to bool on "where approvementState=true"

Tags: c#, compiler-errors

I am using C# and LINQ to SQL in asp.net Entity Framework.

When the checkbox is checked, I want to display list from database which "approvementState" column values are false, and when the checkbox is unchecked; then to get records which columns  approvementState are true.

Html:

```
<asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="cbInternsApproval" Text="View Approved Interns" AutoPostBack="True" Checked="False" OnCheckedChanged="cbInternsApproval_CheckedChanged"/>
```

C# code:

```
protected void cbInternsApproval_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (cbInternsApproval.Checked)
            {
                using (PROJECT_DBEntities3 context=new PROJECT_DBEntities3())
                {

                    var lst=(from f in context.FirstInternships
                                 where f.approvementState==true // error in this line of code
                                 select f).ToList();
                }
            }
        }
```

But I am getting error: Cannot implicitly convert type'bool?' to bool. An explicitconversion exists.

Comment: Don't tag-spam. If there is another question (*after* having fixed the compiler error so the reported behavior is *actually* testable) then ask it as another question.

Comment: Sorry just thought would be related with the error. I changed the question.@user2864740

Comment: Compiler errors happen before the code ever runs. The only information type-errors have to go on is the resolved types of the expressions; it doesn't matter what values the expression will later evaluate to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your code to

```
var lst=(from f in context.FirstInternships
                                 where f.approvementState==true // error in this line of code
                                 select f).ToList();
```

also it seems the property "**approvementState**" is nullable type

try using `f.approvementState.Value == true`

Comment: Checkbox still returns only null everytime and no record is coming.

Comment: checkbox is returning null or query? coz if checkbox is null your "if" condition will throw an error, if query is returning null check your DB for rows satisfying the condition.

Comment: Don't want to confuse you but, if (cbInternsApproval.Checked) --> this if statement is working, I went inside if scope and completed linq query in debugging. But i have no query returning. Also I dont know why string x=Request.Form["cbInternsApproval"]; --> this statement returns null always. if it has something to do with my query's not returning.

Comment: x=Request.Form["cbInternsApproval"]; has nothing to do with your code as you are not using the variable "x" anywhere else, and since no error is thrown, may be you should try to check your DB for related entries, check if you have any rows with approvementState = true in your FirstInternships table

Comment: I have 5 records in DB table, including one true and four false. Column is Bit sql type. And they are 0 and 1

Comment: try to do a lst.Count() after your query, see what value you get by debugging it

Answer (score 1):

where f.approvementState == true

Answer (score 0):

`where (f.approvementState.HasValue && f.approvementState)`

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are not comparing you are assigning value. So change the code to

```
            var lst= (from f in context.FirstInternships
                         where f.approvementState == true 
                         select f).ToList();
```